# differences % and $> command line result end of line

Tags: mac, terminal

For an exercise, I had to make a file print_groups.sh. When I do `sh print_groups.sh` the result should be a list of groups of $USER separated by a comma.

I had two different attempts:

```
groups $FT_USER | tr " " "," | tr -d '\n'
```

with as a result:

```
group,group,group%
```

and

```
groups $FT_USER | tr " " ","
```

with as a result:

```
group,group,group
```

though in the example result in the description of the exercise, this was shown:

```
$>./print_groups
group,group,group,group$>
```

I would expect the $> and % are both end of line chars of the terminal. Does anyone know the difference between the two?

Comment: What does the `groups` command output without any filtering?

Comment: `groups $USER` outputs a list of users from the currents logged in user, like so: `group group group group`

Comment: I don't understand where the `%` comes from. It's not from your commands, and it's not any normal shell prompt. Add a line with just `echo` to the end of your script to compensate for the missing newline in the output.

Comment: I had put `user,user`, which obviously should've been `group,group`

Comment: `groups $USER | tr " " "," | tr -d '\n' && echo '\n' ` outputs `group,group,group`
with an empty line after it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` and the `$>` characters that you see are the terminal prompt. Since you remove the last carriage return with `tr -d '\n'` the script doesn't print a CRLF and the prompt, when exiting the program, shows after your output instead of starting on a new line.

Edit: In linux the prompt is saved in the variable `PS1`, I'm not sure about BSD or Mac. You can view its value with `echo $PS1`.

Comment: thank you for you answer, expected as much. Do you know what the difference is between them? Is it 'just' a terminal setting?

Comment: I assume the % is from a BSD machine and the other is Linux? You can indeed change them in your terminal settings.

Comment: the % is from a mac, the other one I dont know. But thank you for your answer!